# Can I apply conditional formatting in Excel to values that appear more than 6 times?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a large amount of data and I want to highlight email addresses that appear 6 or more times in a given column. Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a formula in you conditional formatting:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1)>=6
```

Where Column A is the column with the addresses.

Comment: Doesn't that only check for 6 or more occurrences of the email in cell A1? Do you mean to use this as part of "conditional formatting?"

Comment: @jpaugh yes it is the formula which one would use in conditional formatting to color the cells that have an email that is entered more than 6 times.

Comment: OP asked for `6 or more` so you forgot the `=` !